# how to calculate 2^1.4

Tags: exponentiation

So I have got a very basic question but it didn't come up as a google search so I am posting it here.

**I want to know how to easy calculate**

`2^1.4 = 2.6390...`

Using `log` and `antilogs` i.e not easy approach ?

i.e.

log y =  log m^n

log y = n log m

log y = 1.4 log 2

log y = 1.4 * 0.301

log y = 0.4214

antilog (log y) = antilog 0.4214

y= antilog 0.4212 (**look for this in a table, should give result**)

What I found on internet ,

turn the decimal into a fraction

2^(1.4) 
=> 2^(1 + 2/5)

now given a^(n + m) = a^n * a^m 
=> 2^1 * 2^(2/5) 
=> 2 * 2^(2/5)

you can stop there if you want to.

however a^(nm) = (a^n)^m

**=> 2 * (2^2)^(1/5)**

> //I was ok till here what to do next to get the right result !

which would be read as 2 times the 5th root of 2 squared and would be the exact answer. [the nth root of a = a^(1/n)]

Comment: Yes, $2\left(\sqrt[5]{2}\right)^2$ is a right answer. What do you want? Decimal approximation?

Comment: Yes , I have such options 2.6390 , 2.xx

Comment: Are you allowed to use $\log$ tables?

Comment: No as I have mentioned I want the easiest way no logs no scientific calculator !

Comment: Also you can note that, $$2^{1.4}\approx 2^{1.5} = \sqrt{8} \approx 2.828$$

Comment: I am looking for a method to calculate this , the digits and exponent can always change

Comment: I posted a method. Does it work for you?

Comment: $2^{1.4}=\frac{2^{\pi}}{4}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Newtons approximation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method%E2%80%8E).

We want to find $x=2^{1.4}$, or equivalently, $x^5=\left(2^{1.4}\right)^5=2^7=128$

Define $f(x)=x^5-128$

We want to find the root of $f(x)$

as noted in my comment, $x\approx \sqrt{8} \approx 2.828$

So we start with this guess of $2.828$.

We put it into the formula,

$$x'=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

and $x'$ will be a more accurate guess.

$$x'= 2.828 - \frac{(2.828)^5-128}{5(2.828)^4}$$

with a bit of hand calculation we get $x'=2.66\ldots$ which is very close to the actual value.

Comment: This sounds easy! But the second digit after decimal is not close enough i.e. 2.66 is way different from 2.63 if there are two options 2.64 , 2.65 , 2.66 . :/

Comment: you can use more iterations of Newton's method to get better approximations

Comment: @prateek you can repeat the same process with the new guess of $2.66$ :) Follow the link I posted. It explains more.

Comment: oh that's cool ;)

Comment: @Sabyasachi. Your answer if fine as long as you can rationalize the exponent. What about $2^\pi$ ? I am just pushing to the limits. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You could simply replace $\pi$ with an approximation to $\pi$ and use the method.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Considering that I am *approximating* anyway I can just be a physicist and say $\pi = \frac{22}{7}$ for large values of $\pi,22$ and $7$

Answer (score 6):

$$2^{1.4}=e^{1.4\ln 2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1.4\ln 2)^k}{k!}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're allowed to use that Log(2) = .693147... or not. If you are you can do the following:

2^1.4 = 2 2^.4 = 2 2^.5 2^-.1 .

Now you need only approximate 2^-.1 . 2^-x for small x:
    2^-x = 1 - Log[2] x + 1/2 Log[2]^2 x^2 - 1/6 Log[2]^3 x^3 + ...

Now set x=0.1 and keep as many terms as needed for your desired accuracy. You get
2^x = 1, .9307..., .933088..., .933032..., .933033.... . The last of these (.933033) is accurate to 6 decimal places. Thus your answers are

2 Sqrt[2] 2^-.1 =
2.82843... (just keeping the leading term of 1), 
2.63238... (keeping x), 
2.63917... (keeping x & x^2), 
2.63901... (keeping up to 3rd order), 
2.63902... (up to 4th order), 
2.63902... (up to 50th order)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a multiple choice question then you can also try the possible answers using Sabyasachi's equation: if $x$ is such that $2^{1.4}=x$ then $x^5=128$.
Therefore, if the answers are $2.63,2.64$ and $2.65$ then calculate $2,64^5$. You will see that it is larger then $128$ so you also want to try $2,63^5$ and choose whichever is closer to 128.

Answer (score -1):

2^1.4 =(1+1)^1.4   approximately 
           =1+1×1.4     approximately 
           =1+1.4         approximately 
           =2.4             approximately 
For the above I used binomial theorem

Comment: Is this an answer?